# Does it matter to make properties protected when they inherit an interface

Tags: c#, oop

I wonder whether the following properties: TakeProfitRatio, StopLossRatio and TrailingStop should be `protected` since the interface they inherit (`ITradingStrategy`), kinda specifies what's visible and what's not. Does it really matter if I make them `protected`?

I will describe the class members below, so you can get the idea.

#### Property explanation:

The abstract properties MUST be overriden by the derived class (marked as required below).
The virtual properties may or may not be overriden by the derived classes (marked as optional).

- TimeFrame - visible to everything, **required**
- TakeProfitRatio, StopLossRatio and TrailingStop - visible to StrategyBase and its derived classes, **optional**
- StartupCandleCount - visible to everything, **optional**
- GetStrategyName() - visible to everything
- StopLossReached(...) - visible to StrategyBase only
- Prepare - visible to everything, **required**

```cs
public interface ITradingStrategy
{
    TimeFrame TimeFrame { get; }

    int StartupCandleCount { get; }

    string GetStrategyName();
    List<TradeAdvice> Prepare(List<Candle> candles);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : ITradingStrategy
{
    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);

    public abstract TimeFrame TimeFrame { get; }

    public virtual decimal? TakeProfitRatio { get; }
    public virtual decimal? StopLossRatio { get; }
    public virtual bool TrailingStop { get; }

    public virtual int StartupCandleCount { get; }

    public string GetStrategyName() => GetType().Name;
    
    public abstract List<TradeAdvice> Prepare(List<Candle> candles);
    
    private (bool SellFlag, SellType SellType) StopLossReached(Trade trade, decimal currentRate)
    {
        ... implementation ...
    }
}

public class RsiStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);

    public override TimeFrame TimeFrame => TimeFrame.FiveMinutes;

    public override decimal? TakeProfitRatio => 0.05m;

    public override int StartupCandleCount => 800;

    public override List<TradeAdvice> Prepare(List<Candle> candles)
    {
        ... implementation ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no *should be protected*. They can be public or protected, both will work.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, yes but what's more correct? To make them protected or let them stay public since they can be visible by StrategyBase (the base class) and its derived classes, e.g. RsiStrategy only

Comment: I suppose it depends on: Is the interface public? And do you care if the functions show up in Intellisense

Comment: @Charlieface, the interface is public. These 3 properties should not be visible outside StrategyBase and its derived classes on the IntelliSense

Comment: Sorry just realised you were talking about the 3 properties *not* in the interface, if so who cares, do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface doesn't say anything about `TakeProfitRatio`, `StopLossRatio` and `TrailingStop`. The spec calls for them to be *visible to StrategyBase and its derived classes* - they thus need to be `protected`, otherwise someone can say:

```
StrategyBase x = new RsiStrategy (..)
x.TakeProfitRatio ..
```

Or even:

```
ITradingStrategy x = new RsiStrategy (..)
(x as RsiStrategy).TakeProfitRatio ..
```

Just because the interface doesn't mention them, doesn't change their presence or accessibility

---

Unless when you say it's "optional" you mean that this accessibility restriction is optional.. ?

Comment: Optional means that the derived classes like RsiStrategy may optionally override them to set real values. Their default values are either null or 0.

Comment: Thank you for that example! It was a good one. So, it's good to do a double check.